# RegEx - Match everything before a word

Tags: regex

I would like to select everything above the specified word. In my case "https".

Imagine the text:

```
TestFileA
TestFileC/E
TestFileD
https:soemthing.com
```

I would like to extract:

```
TestFileA
TestFileC/E
TestFileD
```

I have tried:

```
(?:(?!https).)*
```

but it extracts everything except letter "h"

I also find the solution when the text is in one line but this is not the case for me.. TestFiles need to be separated by new line (\n).

Comment: What programming language (or regex flavor) are you using?

Comment: `[\s\S]*(?=https:)` should work in most of the regex flavors but do mention your regex platform.

Comment: The regex provided should work in most regex flavors - just be sure to use the `SingleLine` option so that `.` matches new lines, and don't use the `global` option, because that will cause it to keep going after the first match, which allows it to skip past the `h` and match the rest of that line.

Comment: What should be done if the input contains the string `https:` more than once?

Comment: @ZaelinGoodman There is no `.` in the suggested regex. However, I would suggest that the regex be either `[\s\S]*?(?=https:)` (or `.*?(?=https:)` with the `SingleLine` option) in case there are multiple occurences of `https:` and we want to process each one separately.